# Implementing 3-way merge editor using CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-6

I want to implement a 3-way merge editor. I found out that CodeMirror v5 supported this feature. But the version 6(current verison) of CodeMirror only supports 2-way merge. My question is, Would I miss out anything If I use the 3-way merge feature available in CodeMirror V5? Is it still relevant? What are the major changes Version 6 has incorporated that v5 doesn't?

[3-way merge in Version 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L6Ya.png)